# Incorrect syntax near 'ON'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'OeeQualityDefects'))

 BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OeeQualityDefects](
    [CharID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [QualityCharID] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

Here I am trying to put a condition if the table is already exist in database if it is not there I suppose to create a table

But, if I run this query I am getting errors

> Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

Comment: 'GO' is not sql syntax it is a batch separator in SSMS, so if you use it anywhere in the middle of a sql transaction, Sql Server will not recognize it and throw and error.

Answer (score 6):

Put the statements containg `GO` before the `IF` statement

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
             FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
             WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
             AND  TABLE_NAME = 'OeeQualityDefects')) 
BEGIN    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OeeQualityDefects]
    (
      [CharID] [int] NOT NULL,
      [QualityCharID] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

`GO` ends a statement and the `IF` statement breaks.

Comment: is it make change of query?

Comment: @user3008105 no it will not change your query it will only Change the Sql Server Setting before starting the sql transaction, whereas you were trying to change the setting in the middle of your transaction.